# How to make the size of Dialogue fragment expand just until below the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialogfragment

I'd like to be able to make the dialogue fragment expand like the one in wunderlist, where the dialog takes the entire screen but doesn't overlap the toolbar.